# Use sed to print lines that start with z and do not end in 03

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I need to print the lines in a text file using the sed command that start with z and do not end in 03. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Why `sed` and not `grep`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is one way to do this

`sed -n '/^z/ { /03$/! p }' <file.txt`